# Filtering and reassigning based on regex in Spark

Tags: pyspark, sparkr

[image]

I have a Spark `DataFrame` named `df`, as shown in the picture above. There is a column named `region` that is currently has only the value `NE`. There is a separate column named `address` with many addresses. I want to change the observations of `region` to `VA` where `address` ends with `VA`. How can I do this? Either `pyspark` or `sparkr` commands would work.

Comment: checkout [`endswith`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.endswith) operator  from `pyspark.sql.functions`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the below snippet should work. This method converts the Dataframe to RDD and performs a map operation to change region appropriately.

```
>>> df = sc.parallelize([("NE","NE"), ("Luray, VA", "NE"), ("VA" ,"NE"), ("Richmond, VA",  "NE")]).toDF(["address", "region"])
>>> df.rdd.map(lambda (x,y): (x,'VA' if x.endswith('VA') else y)).toDF(["address", "region"]).show()
+------------+------+
|     address|region|
+------------+------+
|          NE|    NE|
|   Luray, VA|    VA|
|          VA|    VA|
|Richmond, VA|    VA|
+------------+------+
```

the approach without having convert dataframe to rdd would look like the below. Note: this approach is preferable over the rdd approach since it is more performant and makes less assumptions about the schema.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
df = sc.parallelize([("NE","NE"), ("Luray, VA", "NE"), ("VA" ,"NE"), ("Richmond, VA",  "NE")]).toDF(["address", "region"])
regionfunc = udf(lambda x: 'VA' if x.endswith('VA') else x)
df.withColumn('region', regionfunc(df.address)).show()

+------------+------+
|     address|region|
+------------+------+
|          NE|    NE|
|   Luray, VA|    VA|
|          VA|    VA|
|Richmond, VA|    VA|
+------------+------+
```

Comment: Would this work even if there are more columns than 2 in the `DataFrame`?

Comment: yes it would but the map lamba function has to be changed. alternatively you can use withColumn option defined the dataframe..

Comment: @GauravBansal updated the answer that uses dataframes and should work for any number of columns..